# Run Silverlight 3 standalone

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

So I have a small Silverlight application that plays a slideshow of pictures.  What I want to do is burn the application to a cd and mail the cd to my mother so that she can run the silverlight application on her computer.  I am using Silverlight 3.  How do I create a standalone silverlight application/player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things come to mind:

1. Why can't your end-user just use the internet for that?
2. Any Silverlight app running on a machine would require Silverlight be installed.
3. Assuming the end-user has Silverlight installed, you can burn a copy of the Silverlight XAP + TestPage.html and have the end-user open up the HTML page. You might even create an autoplay file to do that once the CD is in the drive.
   I'd also include the Silverlight install EXE on that disc and maybe fire it up with a silent install with the autoplay script.
4. OOB isn't what you're looking for. 
   OOB requires that the app be first viewed, then installed locally.
   There OOB doesn't support "View me without installing me" mode.

Answer (score 6):

[What's New in Silverlight 3](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/)

> Silverlight 3 Out of Browser Capabilities
>
> The new out of browser experience in
>   Silverlight 3 enables users to place
>   their favorite Silverlight
>   applications directly onto their PC
>   and Mac, with links on the desktop and
>   start menu—all without the need to
>   download an additional runtime or
>   browser plug-in. Further, the new
>   experience enables Silverlight
>   applications to work whether the
>   computer is connected to the Internet
>   or not—a radical improvement to the
>   traditional Web experience.....

[How to Create an Out of Browser Application.](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/07/21/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-108-how-to-create-an-out-of-browser-application.aspx)

[Silverlight 3 as a Desktop Application](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-as-a-Desktop-Application-Out-of-Browser-Applications.aspx)

Comment: Out of Browser Capabilities still require users to install Silverlight through browser.